# Check if list is nested

Tags: python

Is there any way to check if a list is nested without using any built in python functions?
Right now I have:

```
if type(my_list[0]) == list:
    # other code
```

I am working on an assignment problem and need to check if an element in a list is a nested list but I am not allowed to use the type() function or isinstance(). Does anyone what else I can use here?

Comment: what else you can not use?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I am only allowed to use len(), str(), append(), extend(), and int()

Comment: "without using any built in python functions" this sounds like a strange condition. Homework question?

Comment: an exercise, but `my_list[0][0:0] == []`

Comment: @Chris_Rands Won't that throw an error if the type is not a sequence?

Comment: @iz_ sure, can wrap it in try-except

Comment: this is very inefficient, but maybe you could try using try/except and check if you can access it as a list?

Comment: Use nested loops and the [in](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in) operator.

Comment: @ChristianB. Yeh its a homework question lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that tries to do something to the element that only a list can do. if it fails, it's not a list. So:

```
import copy
def check_list(sample_list, index_to_check):
    try:
        new_list = copy.deepcopy(sample_list)
        val = new_list[index_to_check].append('random')
        return True
    except:
        return False

a_list = ['foo', 'baz', ['foo', 'baz']]

print(check_list(a_list, 0))
print(check_list(a_list, 2))
```

this returns:

```
False
True
```

Comment: Any class could have a `.append()` method, it does not guarantee it's a list

Comment: @Chris_Rands: and even worse, regardless what it is, it will frequently change the state of that object :(

Comment: @Chris_Rands integers, floats, dictionaries, and strings don't have append attributes- if he is getting more complex than that, sure use another method.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem good catch, I added a deep copy to the function so it wouldn't change the original object

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it would be much better to simply check for the method anyway, e.g. `hasattr([], 'append')`

Comment: @Chris_Rands he cannot use built in functions so hasattr([], 'append') was not an option.

Comment: ok then `try: item.append` and `except AttributeError:` etc. then- still no need to actually use the method to check it exists

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to bend the rules, you can always check the `__class_` attribute which represents the class to which a class instance belongs and technically it is not a function:

```py
 a=[]
a.__class__
#<class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [[], 0, 1, 'string', (1,2), [1,2,3], {}]

def is_list(lst, idx):
    try:
        return lst[idx] * 0 == []
    except:
        return False

print(is_list(l, 0))
print(is_list(l, 1))
print(is_list(l, 2))
print(is_list(l, 3))
print(is_list(l, 4))
print(is_list(l, 5))
print(is_list(l, 6))
```

Prints:

```
True
False
False
False
False
True
False
```

Comment: this only seperates numeric values (int, float etc.) from other types

Comment: Strings, tuples, etc. will not be equal to zero, and still multiply with a number as well.

Comment: Add a try-except, e.g. in case they had a dict in there

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the if statement to:

```
if '[' in str(nestedLis[0]):
```

The other answers both work well but if anyone was wondering how I solved it without using a separate function.